# get specific array keys back in javascript ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've got the following ajax request that I want to run every 5 seconds.  To test it, I just set up a couple alerts.  I set up an `alert('hello');` inside the success and it fired every 5 seconds.  So that works.

What isnt working is the `if(response.update==true){` section.

I am setting

`<?php $data['update'] = "true"; return $data; ?>` inside the ajax url file.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this an incorrect approach?  Am I missing something?

I even tried setting `datatype: json,` inside ajax and returning `return json_encode($data);` inside ajax url as well with no success.

### CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        /* AJAX request to checker */
        setInterval(
            function (){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo http() . $websitedomain .'/Manage/order_management/search_orders_checker.php'; ?>',
                datatype: html,
                data: { counter:10 },
                success: function(response){ 
                    if(response.update==true){
                    alert('yes');
                    }
                }
            })
        },5000);
        });
    </script>
```

---

---

### EDIT

console log is now reporting the json response.  But the `if (response.update == "true") { alert('yes'); }` still isnt working.

The console.log response: `{"update":"true"}` and its updating every 5 seconds like its supposed to.

Comment: Are you setting a `Content-Type` header on the server? Edit: I should say, that's a shot-in-the-dark question. You really need to provide 1) the relevant server code, and 2) a sample response, including headers, in order for any realistic diagnosis to be possible.

Comment: I don't think I am

Comment: Do a console.log(response) and tell us what you get.

Comment: @KDJ, see my edited comment above. I'm going to refrain from speculation until more information is available.

Comment: `datatype: html` is your problem - try `datatype: "json"` (note the double-quotes as well, it's meant to be a string), then jQuery will try and convert the response into JSON for you. And yes you need `json_encode($data);` on the server as well, and you need to actually echo that data somewhere so it gets output into the response - it would really help if you'd show us more of the relevant PHP code too.

Comment: Also if you want to return a boolean, then `$data['update'] = true` (i.e. without the quotes round `true`) would be more correct - then it's a boolean in PHP as well. Due to weak typing in both languages you might get away with it as it is, but better to be more accurate if you can.

Comment: You should also learn how to use your browser's Network tools to watch HTTP requests (including AJAX requests) and see what data goes back and forth in them, what status are returned, what headers are set etc. It makes debugging them 100 times easier.

Comment: I agree :)  Thanks for the suggestions @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson - you rock.  The return was the issue, partially.  Now, console log reports {"update":true} every 5 seconds; however, the success function alert isnt firing inside `response.update==true`

Comment: Did you change to `datatype: "json"` yet?

Comment: @ADyson yes I have

Comment: I had to parse the json response.  `var obj = JSON.parse(response);`   now it works

Comment: Sorry it should be `dataType` with a capital T. JS vars are case sensitive. And you need to make sure you did `$data['update'] = true` in the PHP as I suggested. Mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/6s9Lvpbg/4/ , static mock data source: http://myjson.com/qz9aw

Comment: @ADyson - that fixed it without having to parse the json.  Can you post all of that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are all the things you need to get it working:

1) PHP:

you need to

- encode your data as JSON
- echo your data to your script's output, rather then returning it somewhere within PHP
- return a boolean `true` instead of a string `"true"` in the "update" field

Here's the new code for that:

```
<?php 
  $data['update'] = true; 
  echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

2) JavaScript:

You need to change `datatype: html` to `dataType: "json"`

This is because

- JS variables are case-sensitive, so jQuery doesn't recognise an
  option called 'datatype'
- the value "json" must be string (before you used `html` which was actually a reference to a non-existent variable
- specifying "json" tells jQuery to automatically parse the response as JSON, meaning you don't have to do you own call to `JSON.parse()`
  in the callback.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would down vote this.  If they took the time to read through everything that has occured during this, they'd see that you helped throughout the entire process and this was a recap.  Anyways.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: or it was because I didnt accept the "other" answer that didnt fully solve the problem.  Either way...it is what it is.  Because all of a sudden my question was downvoted too...haha

Answer (score 0):

Couple things look incorrect here.  First off...

```
<?php $data['update'] = "true"; return $data; ?>
```

If this is how you are returning your data, then this is not returning json.  You need to encode the associative array into json and *echo* that to the standard out.

```
<?php $data['update'] = "true"; echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

Once you have that, then you can make your ajax request expect the response to be json.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo http() . $websitedomain .'/Manage/order_management/search_orders_checker.php'; ?>',
  //dataType tells ajax to auto-parse the json response into an object
  dataType: 'json', 
  data: { counter:10 },
  success: function(response){ 
    if(response.update==true){
      alert('yes');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: if you read the text, I said I even tried to set json and return json_encode($data) and that didnt work.  I've tried returning html and json both.  But I am trying a few suggestions to see if they will resolve this.

Comment: If you did the things in this answer, and did not successfully get a response, then some other issue is happening that is not apparent.  Did you `console.log(response)` to see what you were getting?

Comment: @Taplar `return` on its own won't echo anything into the response. That could be the issue. We can't see enough of the PHP IMO. KDJ could easily confirm this by posting more code and/or doing the suggested console.log

Comment: @ADyson  oh, snap, that's very true.

Comment: @ADyson - you rock. The return was the issue, partially. Now, console log reports {"update":true} every 5 seconds; however, the success function alert isnt firing inside `response.update==true`